# How to create animated splash screen in android TWA( trusted web activity )

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen, twa

I am trying to create animated splash screen using TWA in android studio.

I can attach only PNG, JPEG file but not able to attach GIF file. And not able to customize splash screen.

Comment: Please post a code you tried so far. SO is not a code writing service.community can only help if you took some steps ahead

Answer (score 0):

The Trusted Web Activity Splash Screen doesn't support animations (AnimationDrawable). Animated GIFs are not supported natively on Android.

Slightly related, there's an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1054736&q=component%3AUI%3EBrowser%3EMobile%3ETrustedWebActivities&can=2) on supporting SVGs and 9patch images.